# How to load "playlist" of a users likes into SoundCloud JS Widget Embedded Player?

Tags: javascript, widget, soundcloud

Is it possible to load a users likes into a SoundCloud JS Widget like in the following example on their site?

https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html

Answer (score 0):

The SC widget is able to take playlists and list the tracks out like that, but you will not be able to use their widget and add songs in succession like that.

In order you play songs one after another you'll need to use the SC.Widget.Events found here: [SC Widget Events Documentation](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#events)

You can listen for when the track is finished and add a function when that event occurs to put the next track into the iframe `src`.  You could build a player that lists the songs in succession similar to Soundcloud's.

The only way to get Soundcloud's widget to display a list of songs like that is to use a Soundcloud playlist.